# Find syscalls whitelisted by seccomp

Tags: c, system-calls, seccomp

So I stumbled across a program in C that uses seccomp to filter out a few syscalls. Is there anyway, other than bruteforcing, to find out the syscalls that are actually allowed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you can compile the C program, you can call [seccomp_export_pfc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_export_bpf.3.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [Kafel](https://github.com/google/kafel), write a policy and disassemble the generated eBPF code with its dump_policy_bpf tool.